# SQLCMD Connection error handling

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

When running multiple `:CONNECT` statements within a T-SQL script if one fails to connect, the rest of the script is not ran.

Is there some SQLCMD commands to work as a Try/Catch block to handle the connection error? I am aware that a T-SQL Try/Catch would not be valid as SQLCMD commands are ran before the SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your sqlcmd code inside a batch file and then execute the batch file (as suggested [here](http://www.haidongji.com/2006/03/07/sqlcmd-error-handling/)).

You can use option `-S` to specify the server you want to connect to, and option `-Q` to specify your TSQL code (more info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms162773.aspx)).

For example:

```
sqlcmd -S WrongServerName -Q "select @@servername"
sqlcmd -S CorrectServerName -Q "select @@servername"

pause
```

the first command will fail (if `WrongServerName`  is a non-existing or offline server), while the second one will be executed (if `CorrectServerName` is an online server) and will return the name of the server.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any solutions other than using batch files? The reason I ask is that the scripts are taken from a column inside a table and then joined together to make one large script that runs through multiple servers

Comment: @RyanGillooly Yes, I see your point: I don't know if there is a more advanced mechanism for error handling in SQLCMD. I use this approach because I execute simple TSQL instructions, so batch files are a good solution for me. I understand that if you have to run complex scripts this solution would probably be inadequate. I once read about ERRORLEVEL variable, but I think it only handles errors returned by DOS commands. I'm sorry that I am unable to help you further.